# Create variables from array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below array with values

```
Na = [8289,92198,820624,84225,55775,98679,76317,8621,75928]
```

What I am expecting is 9 variables to be created as there are 9 values in this array. These 9 variables have to be dynamically created, as the values in the array changes.

Below is what I tried, but no luck.

```
for (var i = 1; i < na.length; i++) {
    window["na"+i] = new nas();
}

logInfo("na7" + na7);
```

Comment: but why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Store them in an object, creating n global variables is a horrible horrible methodology

Comment: @zzzzBov Classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: is it possible what you're after are nine instances based on the data in the array, and not nine separate variable declarations?

Answer (score 12):

Try like this,

```
var Na = [8289,92198,820624];
var [na1, na2, na3] = Na;
console.log(na1, na2, na3);
```

**Edit:**

```
var Na = [8289,92198,820624];
var variable_names = {};
for(var i = 0; i< Na.length; i++){
   variable_names['na_'+i] = Na[i];
}
//console.log(variable_names);
console.log(variable_names.na_0);
```

Comment: what happens when there're N number of values in "na" array.based on the array length the variable names have to be created

Comment: This answer is very useful to directly get and directly list the results from array of Promises to variables.